# Adding Data Attribute To Option

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "ajax-ongkir.php?destination=" + subdistrictId + "&destination_type=subdistrict&weight=" + weight,
  dataType: "JSON",
  success: function(json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

      var courierName = json[i].name;
      var courierService = json[i].service;
      var courierTarif = json[i].tarif;

      $('.courier').append($('<option>', {
        value: courierName + ' ' + courierService + ' ' + courierTarif,
        text: courierName + ' - ' + courierService + ' - ' + courierTarif
      }));

      $('.courier').$('<option>').last().attr('data-tarif', courierTarif);

    }
  }
});
```

but this line doesn't work:

```
$('.courier').$('<option>').last().attr('data-tarif', courierTarif);
```

How to add `courierTarif` as data attribute into `<option>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong selection.

Replace:

```
 $('.courier').$('<option>')
```

with:

```
$('.courier option')
```

Now your `last()` selector work.

```js
$('.courier option').last().attr('dat-tarif', "hi");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="courier">
  <option value="a">1</option>
  <option value="b">2</option>
  <option value="c">3</option>
</select>
```

Alternative you can use `find`.

```js
$('.courier').find('option').last().attr('dat-tarif', "hi");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="courier">
  <option value="a">1</option>
  <option value="b">2</option>
  <option value="c">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solve my problem.

```
$('.courier option:last').attr('data-tarif', courierTarif);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to try like this.

> $('.courier option[value="3"]').attr('data-tarif', "hi");

```js
$('.courier option[value="3"]').attr('data-tarif', "hi");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="courier">
  <option value="1">opt1</option>
  <option value="2">opt2</option>
  <option value="3">opt3</option>
</select>
```